# How to read notifications using D-Bus and Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dbus

I was developing simple application, which reads notifications from D-Bus and does some stuff upon receiving it.

This turned out to be quite a headache so I am sharing my code with you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import gi.repository.GLib
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

def notifications(bus, message):
    # do your magic

DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
bus.add_match_string_non_blocking("eavesdrop=true, interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications', member='Notify'")
bus.add_message_filter(notifications)

mainloop = gi.repository.GLib.MainLoop()
mainloop.run()
```